# Flood of GC_CONCURRENT freed messages, not my app

Tags: android, garbage-collection

I'm getting a flood of GC_CONCURRENT freed messages in LogCat and **they are not coming from my own app** (I force closed my app to be sure).  The memory freed is very consistent (about 1430K) and it occurs about 6 times per second.

How can I troubleshoot this?

It's interfering with my app development because it floods LogCat and forces valuable log statements out of the buffer and also causes LogCat to "jiggle" because the session filter jumps up and down one line each time a GC_CONCURRENT event occurs.

The phone is a Motorola Atrix 2 running Android 2.3.5.  I use the phone for development only so it has almost no additional apps than the stock bloatware from AT&T.

```
11-14 10:50:14.117: D/dalvikvm(724): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1426K, 52% free 4712K/9671K, external 2357K/2773K, paused 3ms+3ms
11-14 10:50:14.273: D/dalvikvm(724): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1426K, 52% free 4714K/9671K, external 2357K/2773K, paused 2ms+3ms
11-14 10:50:14.429: D/dalvikvm(724): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1431K, 52% free 4712K/9671K, external 2357K/2773K, paused 2ms+3ms
11-14 10:50:14.585: D/dalvikvm(724): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1426K, 52% free 4714K/9671K, external 2357K/2773K, paused 2ms+3ms
11-14 10:50:14.742: D/dalvikvm(724): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1428K, 52% free 4714K/9671K, external 2357K/2773K, paused 2ms+3ms
11-14 10:50:14.898: D/dalvikvm(724): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1430K, 52% free 4713K/9671K, external 2357K/2773K, paused 2ms+3ms
11-14 10:50:15.054: D/dalvikvm(724): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1427K, 52% free 4714K/9671K, external 2357K/2773K, paused 2ms+3ms
11-14 10:50:15.210: D/dalvikvm(724): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1432K, 52% free 4711K/9671K, external 2357K/2773K, paused 2ms+3ms
11-14 10:50:15.367: D/dalvikvm(724): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1426K, 52% free 4712K/9671K, external 2357K/2773K, paused 3ms+2ms
11-14 10:50:15.523: D/dalvikvm(724): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1426K, 52% free 4714K/9671K, external 2357K/2773K, paused 2ms+3ms
11-14 10:50:15.679: D/dalvikvm(724): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1432K, 52% free 4711K/9671K, external 2357K/2773K, paused 3ms+3ms
11-14 10:50:15.835: D/dalvikvm(724): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1426K, 52% free 4712K/9671K, external 2357K/2773K, paused 3ms+2ms
11-14 10:50:15.992: D/dalvikvm(724): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1426K, 52% free 4714K/9671K, external 2357K/2773K, paused 2ms+2ms
11-14 10:50:16.148: D/dalvikvm(724): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1429K, 52% free 4713K/9671K, external 2357K/2773K, paused 3ms+3ms
11-14 10:50:16.304: D/dalvikvm(724): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1429K, 52% free 4712K/9671K, external 2357K/2773K, paused 3ms+3ms
11-14 10:50:16.460: D/dalvikvm(724): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1426K, 52% free 4714K/9671K, external 2357K/2773K, paused 2ms+3ms
11-14 10:50:16.617: D/dalvikvm(724): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1430K, 52% free 4713K/9671K, external 2357K/2773K, paused 3ms+3ms
11-14 10:50:16.773: D/dalvikvm(724): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1429K, 52% free 4712K/9671K, external 2357K/2773K, paused 3ms+3ms
11-14 10:50:16.929: D/dalvikvm(724): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1426K, 52% free 4714K/9671K, external 2357K/2773K, paused 3ms+3ms
```

Comment: Just to be extra extra sure it's not my app, I uninstalled it.  Still getting the GC messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The process ID is shown in the message (in the above, it's pid 724).  You can use `adb shell ps` to get the Linux process dump; find the entry for pid 724 to see which app it is.

Alternatively, if you're on a developer device, within Eclipse/ADT/DDMS you can open the "Devices" view and see all processes.  Select the app with the matching pid (second column), then open the "Threads" view.  This shows all the threads in the app.  Look for a thread with high values in the "utime" and "stime" columns.  If you double-click on it a few times, you will see snapshots of the stack trace that might suggest what's causing all the GCs.

Comment: Thanks. This helped me find the culprit: 

$ ./adb shell ps|grep 724

system    724   268   204160 45808 ffffffff 00000000 S com.motorola.process.system

Comment: ... although that still means there's nothing I can do about it.  Sigh.

Comment: You may be able to beat it into quiescence by killing the current instance from Settings > Apps.  It won't go away, but it might stop spinning (which is likely unhealthy for your battery life as well as annoying in logcat).

Comment: I'd like to try that, but I'm having trouble correlating "com.motorola.process.system" (pid 724) with an app. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: If you go into Settings > Apps > All you should be able to find it in the list.  Select it and use "Force stop".  (The Settings > Apps stuff has changed a fair bit over time -- I think 2.3.x had this feature, but I can't remember.)